# Ошибка при резервном копировании базы данных Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

При выполнении команды `manage.py dumpdata > db.json` получаю ошибку

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-177: character maps to <undefined>
Exception ignored in: <generator object cursor_iter at 0x000001FAB1C32110>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Lessons\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1934, in cursor_iter
    cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Погуглил в [АнглоСтеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457733/django-dumpdata-fails-on-special-characters), и нашёл решение. Необходимо воспользоваться режимом UTF-8.

```
python -Xutf8 ./manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```